# Create Cloud Composer environment with a private repository using Terraform

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-composer, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to create a Cloud Composer environment with a PyPI package from a private repository using Terraform. Cloud Composer [supports private PyPI repositories](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-private). However, configuring a private repository requires an existing composer bucket.

When using [Terraform to create an environment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/composer_environment), the bucket and environment is created in one go. As far as I can see, the environment creation will fail before there is a chance to write the configuration file to the bucket. Is there any way to create a Cloud Composer environment with a private repository using Terraform?

This is roughly what I'm trying to do:

```
resource "google_composer_environment" "test" {
  provider = google-beta
  project = var.project_id
  region = var.region
  config {
    software_config {
      image_version = "composer-2.0.0-airflow-2.1.4"
      pypi_packages = {
        mypackage = "*"  # from a private PyPI repo
      }
    ...
```

Comment: Please update your question with your config.

Comment: I'm kind of confuse on what are you trying to achieve to create the composer environment  with a custom repository. As described on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/quickstart#create_an_environment) , bucket is created when the environment is created. You want to use a custom bucket?? or you want to use a custom image?? (you can only use the ones in the [official list](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions#images))

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard , updated the question. However, I'm getting convinced that this is a design issue in Cloud Composer. Even omitting Terraform and just using gcloud API directly, it seems it is not possible to create a Cloud Composer Environment with a private PyPI repository in one go. As far as I can see, it requires first creating the environment and then modifying it after it has been created.

Comment: Thanks @Betjens, same as my comment above

Comment: Ok so this is multiple actions within a single API invocation and not two consecutive. That is where I was confused. You may be able to raise a feature request on the provider's GH issue tracker to wrap a workaround into the resource if this is not directly possible within the API endpoint parameters.

Comment: @ollik1 ,You can raise feature request by going directly to the [project hub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues).

Comment: Thanks all, I have opened an issue here https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/10850

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm leaving this as community wiki response for community visibility for this kind of questions. For features, I suggest is to go directly to the project site and request the feature there:

- [Terraform Provider Issues](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues)

This will alert the developers of the missing/requested features and it will be taking into consideration. For this case you can track the progress of this case on the [issue link](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/10850) you created. Also, you can see the list of upconming features/bugs inside the project [goals dashboard](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/milestone/12) but as mention in the description the ETA is up to the team to provide.